# Configuring nginx to protect Windows server from exploits

Tags: javascript, windows, nginx, configuration, server

I am tasked to **protect** our `Windows server` from `SQL injection` and other types of attacks.

I have been asked to use `nginx` but I'm unsure of the steps since it is my first time so I really need assurance.

Here are the steps that I currently have in mind:

1. Copy open-source nginx folder to the Windows server
2. Run the nginx installer
3. Edit the nginx config file
4. Restart the nginx service

Kindly validate if these are the right steps or if I am missing out something.

I am also planning to use the `scripts` from this **link**:

http://www.looklinux.com/secure-your-nginx-web-server-blocking-exploits-file-injections-sql-injections-spam-and-user-agents/

for my `nginx config` file.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is a good choice , and yes steps you described are correct to get it up and running .

The whole thing is in the configuration file , following nginx documentation and good practices will lead to better results .

Instead of restarting nginx everytime you edited the conf file you can first try if the configuration is correct by running `nginx -t` to avoid problems .

Other note is , looking at the link you provided , the use of **if** in the configuration file , it is **NOT** encouraged (See [nginx docs](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/));

> Directive if has problems when used in location context, in some cases it doesn’t do what you expect but something completely different instead. In some cases it even segfaults. It’s generally a good idea to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Hi again, is there a great way to **remediate** this **vulnerability**: `Missing Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie` using `NGINX`? Like by adding a `secure` flag to **all cookies**?

Comment: Hi @JPaulPunzalan , what is the context ? cookies are saved in browser and the user can access/edit them .

Comment: I need to add 'secure' and 'httpOnly' flags on the 'request cookie' to remediate the vulnerability by 'hacking' the `AppScan` tool. `proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; HttpOnly";` is what I added in the `nginx config` file but when I test it back in `chrome`(Developer's tools -> Application Tab -> Cookies Tab), the flags are not checked, meaning the secure and httpOnly flags were not added via the nginx conf file.

Comment: The `Server` attribute in the `Response Header` is also set to `Apache-Coyote/1.1`. Does this mean that `nginx` has **not really had** any effect yet?

Comment: what about `more_set_headers 'Set-Cookie: $sent_http_set_cookie; secure';`

Comment: I am getting `unknown directive "more_set_headers" in C:\nginx/conf/nginx.conf:35` is there something that I should install first?

Comment: yes , missing module  [ngx_headers_more](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module)

Comment: I think this is only for `Linux OS`. Are there any workarounds for `Windows`?

Comment: sorry no idea about that , i'm using nginx on Debian .

Comment: Hi @jirarium, would `proxy_cookie_path` still work on Response Headers that **lack** the `path` attribute? The server response `Set-Cookie` only has the `cookie name` and `expires` attributes. Just checking on where is the wrong in my `config` file